# How to fix error when changing drop down option

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am very new to web scraping, so I still have lots of trouble. Currently, I am trying to web scrape from https://www.enterprisetrucks.com/truckrental/en_US.html by setting the pickup time by running this code:

```
pickupTime = d.find_element_by_id('fldPickuptime_msdd')
pickupTime.click();
select = Select(d.find_element_by_id('fldPickuptime'))
select.select_by_value('20:00')
```

But I get the error saying that the element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown which is present is not of the `Select` type, so you cannot use the `Select` method here. You need to click on the time using the xpath of that element directly.
You can use the xpath:

```
pickupTime = d.find_element_by_id("fldPickuptime_msdd")
pickupTime.click();
selectTime = d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fldPickuptime_msdd']//span[text()='8:00 PM']")
selectTime.click();
```

Code for JavaScriptExecutor Click:

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Enter the xpath here")
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: I was trying to change the return time but when I use the id "fldReturntime_msdd" I get the error message saying ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable why does this happen?

Comment: Also how do you change the date?

Comment: @EricOh 1. "ElementNotInteractableException" comes when the element which you are trying to click is not displayed currently. So you can click the element using javascriptexecutor click
2. You can change the date by sending the required time in the xpath mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @EricOh have added the method for javascript click in the answer. You can use that.

Comment: But why does using the xpath work for the Pickup time but not the return time?

Comment: @EricOh which one is the return time in your question? I cant find any return time in the question

Comment: Its if you go into the link then you can see section where you choose the input time

Comment: Also I tried your method but it didn't change the times. It just continued on with the code without making any changes but didn't throw any errors.

Comment: For the return time, you can use the xpath: `returnTime = d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fldReturntime_msdd']//span[text()='8:00 PM']")` This would work

Comment: And if the time is not changing then you need to use the javascriptexecutor click, please use the code i have mentioned in the answer and replace the xpath in the javascriptexecutor click method and it would work fine